# How to avoid reloading SoundCloud widget in React SPA when linking away and back

Tags: reactjs, iframe, single-page-application, soundcloud

I have a React Single Page Application, and one of the links is a page with an embedded SoundCloud widget. When I link away and come back to that page the widget is reloaded, sending various network requests.

I want to keep my application as lightweight as possible. Is this just the nature of SPAs with an embedded widget? I'm not using Redux. Should I be?

Comment: dont unmount the component

Comment: did you find the solution?